# How much does FreeBSD accept_filter actually improve performance in a modern world?

Tags: http, freebsd, kernel, socket

I recently learned about FreeBSD's [`accept_filter` socket option](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=accept_filter&sektion=9&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) which can allow a worker process to avoid context switching by, for example, waiting until a full HTTP request is received with [`accf_http`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=accf_http&sektion=9):

> This is a filter to be placed on a   socket that will be using accept()
>   to  receive incoming HTTP connections.
>
> It   prevents the application from receiving the connected descriptor
>   via  accept() until either a full HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 HEAD or GET
>   request has  been buffered by the kernel.
>
> If   something other than a HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 HEAD or GET request is
>   received the kernel will allow the    application to receive the
>   connection  descriptor    via accept().
>
> The utility of accf_http is such that a server will not have to
>   context  switch several times before performing the   initial parsing of
>   the  request.  This effectively   reduces the amount of required CPU
>   utilization  to   handle incoming requests by keeping active processes
>   in    preforking  servers such as Apache low  and reducing the size of the
>   file descriptor  set that needs to be managed by interfaces   such
>   as    select(), poll() or  kevent() based servers.

My gut feeling is that on modern hardware, serving traffic to clients on high-speed connections (cable modem/DSL speeds or better) this may be a micro-optimization. Given that `accf_http` can't be used for HTTPS or HTTP/2 connections and `accf_data` just waits for the first byte, I don't see much advantage here. Maybe they'd save one or two context switches?

Are there any recent (post-2015 maybe?) benchmarks about how much FreeBSD's `accept_filter` can actually improve performance or throughput/concurrency?

Comment: 1. accf_http was very useful with preforked server like Apache (waiting to full HTTP request happens inside kernel) and less so with nginx which is likely used in 2018. 2. If client sends request fast there will be no benefit from access filter. Most benchmarks can't emulate slow clients and will not show any difference (wich in theory should be very small if nginx is used).

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking @citrin, that today clients send so fast there's not as much benefit provided by `accept_filter`

Comment: Nowadays many clients still has slow connection, but nginx and (and some other web servers which use epoll/kqueue based event loop) can handle a lot of concurrent connections efficiently.

Comment: Most of the search results I'm getting are from around 2011 or older? Doesn't appear to be too relevant today. I wonder if it helps in high load situations?